# Как правильно: она с мужем или они с мужем проснулись?

Tags: согласование, множественное-число, число

Знакомая утверждает, что возможно и так употреблять, и так. Мне кажется, что, раз глагол стоит во множественном числе, лучше сказать «они с мужем». Подтверждения найти не могу. А как правильно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, что правильно:  **Они с мужем проснулись.**

**В данном предложении** мы сначала выбираем форму **мн. числа для сказуемого**, причем на выбор  оказывает влияние **равноправие действий** (см. Розенталь). И уже после этого  (для согласования во мн. числе)  используем местоимение ***они***, а не ***она***.

В других случаях возможно сочетание "**она** с мужем + сказуемое **в ед. числе**". Именно такие варианты встречаются в Нацкорпусе, но там нет сочетания "**она** с мужем + сказуемое **во мн. числе**".

Примеры из Нацкорпуса:

1) В начале революции **она с мужем уехала** за границу и больше не возвращалась. [Н. М. Гершензон-Чегодаева. Воспоминания дочери (1952-1971)]

2) Когда **они с сестрой пошли** в школу, Ольге было восемь, Наташе ― семь. [Маша Трауб. Ласточ…ка (2012)]

У Розенталя разбирается эта тема  §186. Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой   [§186. Сказуемое при подлежащем типа брат с сестрой](http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/64.htm#%D0%B7_04)

....В других случаях играет роль **лексическое значение сказуемого**, например: Мать с дочерью долго не могли успокоиться и вспоминали случившееся **(оба действия могут производиться при равноправном участии субъектов действия**); Коля с Петей поступили в одну и ту же школу; Брат с сестрой возвратились порознь. Ср.: Клычков с Чапаевым разъехались по флангам... (Фурманов).

Comment: Розенталь и говорит. Хотя логически мн.ч. возможно, но все же предпочитается ед.ч. Поэтому возможны варианты.  Они с мужем проснулись. Она с мужем проснулась.

Comment: Хотя, думаю, в примере Она с мужем проснулась - акцент ставится на том, с кем именно проснулась. Т .е. в этом случае речь идет не о равноправных действиях.

Comment: Согласитесь, такое значение тоже странно, если логическое ударение на слове "муж", должно быть продолжение, а не с.. Не идет этот глагол с "она", как и другие из второй части ответа Арины. Мне бы не помешало третье мнение, дело в семантике все-таки.

Answer (score 1):

Обсуждение ушло в сторону от основного вопроса: ОНА или ОНИ? Сказуемое стоит во мн. ч. (*проснулись*). Особенность данного случая в том, что первое слово — местоимение. А если в группу входит местоимение, то сказуемое должно уподобляться числовому значению местоимения. Из двух предложенных вариантов («Она с мужем проснулись» или «Они с мужем проснулись») корректен только один:

**Они с мужем проснулись.**

Вот что говорит об этом [Грамота](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/64-bolshinstvo):

*Академическая «Русская грамматика» отмечает, что «если в группу со значением совместности входит местоимение 1-го или 2-го лица, то глагол в сказуемом, уподобляясь числовому значению местоимения, имеет ту же личную форму, что и это местоимение: Я с отцом (с сестрами) пойду; Мы с отцом (с сестрами) пойдем; Ты с матерью (с сестрами) останешься; Вы с матерью (с сестрами) останетесь».*

Comment: @ М_Г, это и понятно. Об этом никто и не спорит. Вопрос в другом: она с мужем проснулась/они с мужем проснулись. Какой из этих вариантов предпочтителен?

Comment: @Серж Это уже другой вопрос, не тот, что был задан V.V. Мое мнение: в общем случае – "они с мужем проснулись" – действие совместное; в особых случаях  – "она с мужем проснулась" (акцент на муже, сегдня проснулась с мужем, а вчера с любовником).

Comment: Да, согласен с вами!

Comment: М Г. Спасибо огромное, я бы приняла два ответа, если бы  была возможность. Серж, спасибо за "особый случай".

Answer (score 0):

Вот что говорится в книге  "А как лучше сказать?" Д.Э.Розенталь.

**Жена с мужем пошл… в театр**

Если бы мы переставили первые два существительных в этом предложении, то вопрос о согласовании сказуемого с подлежащим решался бы просто: ***Муж с женой пошли в театр (форма множественного числа глагола-сказуемого пошли указывает на синтаксическое равноправие существительных, входящих в Состав подлежащего муж с женой).***
В предложении **Мать с ребенком пошла в консультацию** форма единственного числа глагола-сказуемого пошла указывает на синтаксическое неравноправие существительных в сочетании мать с ребенком, что отражает реальное положение вещей, поскольку производителем действия мыслится только мать.
Как же быть с примером в заголовке, в котором глагол-сказуемое мы оставили без окончания, поставив вместо него многоточие? **Жена с мужем пошли или пошла?** С точки зрения логики форма множественного числа так же приемлема, как и в перевернутом сочетании муж с женой пошли…, и все же предпочтительней сочетание **Жена с мужем пошла в театр.** *Этим отнюдь не подчеркивается зависимое положение мужа в семье, а учитывается необычная* для подобных сочетаний постановка существительного женского рода на первом месте: как правило, **на первое место ставится существительное мужского рода (брат с сестрой, отец с матерью, дед с бабкой и т. п.).** Объясняется это тем, что ***в грамматическом отношении мужской род сильнее, например: Мальчик и девочка шли по улице. Оба они…, (не "обе они…").***

### Ответ Граммы.ру.

При подлежащем, выраженном сочетанием со значением совместности, возможна форма как единственного, так и множественного числа сказуемого. Форма единственного числа предпочтительна, если *а) сказуемое стоит перед подлежащим (Сначала просыпается дедушка с бабушкой); б) если один из участников действия играет ведущую роль в совместном действии, а другой как-либо зависит от него (Мать с ребенком гуляет); в) если в состав сочетания входит личное местоимение* **1-го или 2-го лица единственного числа (Я с отцом поехал на дачу).**

**Ср.: Дедушка с бабушкой просыпаются раньше всех; Петр с Машей учились на филологическом факультете; Мы с отцом поехали на дачу.**

Поэтому в нашем случае правильным вариантом будет: **они с мужем проснулись.**

Comment: Ruscorpora.ru не дает ни одного примера на "она с мужем проснулась/проснулись. Почему?

Comment: ― Ева, где логика? Ваша подруга, она с мужем помирилась?  ― Вроде бы.  [Слава Сэ. Ева (2010)]И фотогалерея ― она с мужем голубей запускает, она с мужем целуется… Толстая стала. [Маша Трауб. Не вся la vie (2008)]После прихода к власти фашистов она с мужем переехала в Париж, много и плодотворно работала, издала еще две книги стихов. [Вадим Баевский. Ассиар // «Знамя», 2005

Comment: Она с мужем уехала в Киев, и ее квартира стояла пустая. [К. И. Чуковский. Серебряный герб (1936)]

Comment: Поступок матери жертвы тем поразительнее, что, как выяснилось, Абдулла был не единственным сыном, которого ***они с мужем потеряли.*** [Захар РАДОВ. Во время казни в Иране мать жертвы спасла жизнь убийце // Комсомольская правда, 2014.04.17]

Comment: Теперь страховая компания должна выплатить вдове 2,1 млн рублей―сумму, которую ***они с мужем должны были*** банку на момент трагедии.

Comment: Моника же говорила, что брак у нее счастливый- двое детей плюс возможность делать все, что хочется из-за того, что ***они с мужем постоянно снимаются*** в разных странах. [Елена ЛАПТЕВА. Звездные разводы лета: Лучше б я съел перед загсом свой паспорт // Комсомольская правда, 2013.09.13]

Comment: Это другие глаголы. А "проснулись" нет.Значение глагола влияет.Арина, похоже, права.

Comment: "Она с мужем проснулась" –звучит по меньшей мере  странновато.

Comment: Дело не в глаголе. В Нац,корпусе примеры распределены так: она  с мужем +ед.ч. Они с мужем +мн.ч.

Comment: Про Нацкорпус верно, но вот выбор мн. числа может зависеть от лексического значения глагола, на что указывает и Розенталь. И в этом случае мы выбираем именно мн. число для данного глагола  (равноправие действий, каждый просыпается сам по себе, а не вместе с кем-то). Для меня ПО СЛУХУ верен только вариант "они с мужем проснулись", другой не воспринимается совершенно.

Answer (score 0):

Вариант "она с мужем" оставляет широкий диапазон восприятия, когда неравноправное распределение степени активности участников действия может предполагать понимания второго актанта в диапазоне от "активного", затем- "исполнителя воли первого актанта" до пассивного "страдательного объекта"(она с мужем возиться целый день"). В реальной жизни говорящий неосознанно выбирает тот или иной вариант, в зависимости от того, как С ЕГО ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ распределяется степень равноправия в активности при совершении совместного действия.
Вариант "они с мужем" однозначно говорит о равноправном распределении инициативы и исполнения действия. В речи мы выбираем тот вариант, который С ТОЧКИ ЗРЕНИЯ НАШЕГО ВОСПРИЯТИЯ ситуации соответствует происходящему.

Что касается конкретной приведённой фразы "она/они с мужем проснулись", то необходимо обратить внимание на тип действия, выраженный глаголом "проснуться", а именно : это самопроизвольное, неконтролируемое действие, независящее от воли актантов, что свидетельствует о том, что в данном конкретном случае нет активных инициаторов или  же пассивных деятелей, подчиняющих и подчинённых.
Значит здесь важен **тип действия**: УПРАВЛЯЕМОЕ или НЕУПРАВЛЯЕМОЕ актантами. Именно поэтому обе фразы(в данном случае неуправляемые актантами), не натыкаясь на какие-нибудь запреты, могут быть использоваться как взаимозаменяющие. Отсюда недоумение, и вопрос.

Когда же имеется управляемое действие, то сразу же появляется потенциал для более активного и менее активного актанта-"управленца".

Сравните (1)"она с мужем гуляли" и (2) они с мужем гуляли. В первом варианте "она была с мужем (чтобы помочь, поддержать его) и они вместе гуляли. Во втором варианте оба гуляли равноправно.

А теперь в нашей фразе с неуправляемым, самопроизвольным действием заменим одного из актантов на такого, который по своей сути нуждается в помощи другого. (1)"они с ребёнком проснулись" и (2)"она с ребёнком проснулись". В первом варианте (1) слышится, что и она, и ребёнок, каждый в своей постели спали и потом проснулись. Во втором варианте (2)кажется, что она была (спала) с ребёнком и они вместе проснулись. То есть теперь важен **ТИП АКТАНТА**, нуждающегося в помощи другого или нет.

Comment: Пожалуйста, для одного ответа используйте одну форму ответа.